# The lua-visual-debug package documentation

Tags: luatex, debugging, lua-visual-debug

The [documentation](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/lua-visual-debug/doc/lvdebug-doc.pdf) is kind of lacking. 
Could anyone explain the meaning of blue solid/dotted lines and red solid lines between words here?
How are they different from the dotted versions?

[image]

Looking into the source code, I see this but I don't understand the color code and the code itself.

[image]

Source: https://tug.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/lua-visual-debug/doc/lvdebug-doc.pdf

Comment: When I click your link and look in that pdf file, the parts you marked in yellow look dotted as well (a bit cramped, but dotted). [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfLoS.png).

Comment: The one are spaces that have been stretched a bit, the other have been shrinked.

Comment: @mickep The image above is the result that I copied the code and compiled myself as plain TeX on Overleaf. It looks different from the image in the documentation.

Comment: Colour coding is RG: red-green-blue RGB model; G = grayscale. values [0-1]. PDF literal commands. Lowercase version rg and g should range [0-255].

Comment: [PDF32000_2008](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) may help if you want to delve into the PDF standard, and what all the PDF literals are. Correction: RG = stroking colour; rg = nonstroking colour (=fill).

Comment: Yes, but I think yours are dotted, but the dots are so close (even overlapping) so that it looks like a line. As @UlrikeFischer writes, because of shrinkage.

Comment: Probably that is true. I was always thinking that glue was fixed in each pargraph. However, this seems that they change on line per line basis.

Comment: @Cicada gray is a bit confusing as G could mean green as well.

Comment: Refer to Table 74 in the PDF spec: `G` and `g` refer to the grayscale colour space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in appearance of the dotted / solid lines are a result of a programming error.

Next version (0.9) will update the documentation and fix the error.

(PDF operator `S` should be used for a dash pattern and not `s`)